# Resolving contact conflict in more than one Mailbox in Microsoft Outlook

Tags: c#, outlook

I am trying to resolve ambiguous contacts in Outlook 2010. My outlook is configured with two different mailboxes say XXX@domain1.com and XXX@domain2.com. If a particular user(say XXX) exist in both domains outlook resolves the name from the default address book. How to switch to the other address book (i,.e domain2) and resolve ? However if the contact doesn't exist in domain1(i,e default) my program can fetch it from domain2. Please suggest me a way to resolve recipient from a particular domain alone.

My application is in C# and i use Microsoft Outlook Library 14.0

Answer (score 1):

If using [Redemption](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption) is an option (I am its author), you can use [RDOAddressList](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/RDOAddressList.htm).ResolveName method to resolve a name against a particular GAL container. `RDOAddressList` object can be retrieved from either [RDOSession.AddressBook](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/rdoaddressbook.htm) or from [RDOExchangeAccount](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/RDOAccount.htm#RDOExchangeAccount).`GAL` property. `RDOExchangeAccount` can be retrieved from the [RDOSession.Accounts](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/RDOAccounts.htm) collection.

VB:

```
  set Session = CreateObject("Redemption.RDOSession")
  Session.MAPIOBJECT = Application.Session.MAPIOBJECT
  set AddressEntry = Session.AddressBook.GAL.ResolveName("dmitry streblechenko")
  MsgBox AddressEntry.SMTPAddress
```

C#:

```
  Redemption.RDOSession session = new Redemption.RDOSession();
  session.MAPIOBJECT = Application.Session.MAPIOBJECT; //if you already have a pointer to the Outlook.Application object, Or call Logon
  Redemption.RDOAddressEntry addressEntry = session.AddressBook.GAL.ResolveName("dmitry streblechenko");
  MessageBox.Show(addressEntry.SMTPAddress);
```

Comment: Can i get the C# code to for RDOAddressList.ResolveName () against a particular GAL container ?

Comment: I am using accounts.DisplayAccountList() to allow user to change the default account..I use  session.AddressBook.ResolveName(name, true) to resolve a name against a particular AddressList (i,e Default in outlook). If the user makes domain2 as default account then will  session.AddressBook.ResolveName(name, true) resolve from domain2 ?

Comment: Yes, the default address list will change.

Comment: i tried the above code which i have posted but the check names dialog still shows names from domain 1 even after setting domain 2 as default account.. please help

Comment: What are your address book name resolution options (Ctrl + Shift B, Tools | Options)?

Comment: "when sending email check address lists in this order"--> "start with global address list" radio button is clicked....In "when opening address list show this address list first" dropdown --->"Global address List" is selected.

Comment: Can you explicitly check against a particular Exchange account? Use RDOExchangeAccount.GAL.ResolveName. RDOExchangeAccount can be retrieved from the RDOSession.Accounts collection.

Answer (score 0):

The Outlook object model doesn't provide any property or method for resolving a recipient against a specific address book. The only possible method is [Resolve](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff862796(v=office.15).aspx) or [ResolveAll](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff867165(v=office.15).aspx) for the Recipients class.

Answer (score 0):

```
   private Redemption.RDOAddressEntry ResolveRecipientsRDO(string name)
   {

        Redemption.RDOAddressEntry raddressEntry = null;
        try
        {  
            string displayName = (string)accountDisplayNames[domainSelect.Text];
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application app = new Outlook.Application();
            Redemption.RDOSession session = new Redemption.RDOSession();
            session.MAPIOBJECT = app.Session.MAPIOBJECT;
            //if you already have a pointer to the Outlook.Application object, Or call Logon
            RDOStores stores = session.Stores;

            RDOAccounts accounts = session.Accounts;
          
            

            if (stores.DefaultStore.Name.ToLower().Equals(displayName.ToLower()))
            {
                WriteLog("Default account:" + stores.DefaultStore.Name.ToLower());
                // MessageBox.Show("Outlook's Default account name: " + stores.DefaultStore.Name.ToLower() + " matches with selected domain " + displayName);
                raddressEntry = session.AddressBook.ResolveName(name, true);

            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("The selected domain " + displayName + " is not Outlook's Default domain. Set this as default domain to resolve", "Default Mailbox Setting");
                accounts.DisplayAccountList();
                WriteLog("Default account:" + stores.DefaultStore.Name.ToLower());
                raddressEntry = session.AddressBook.ResolveName(name, true);

            }
        }
        catch(System.Exception e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Resolving error:" + e.GetBaseException());
            WriteLog("*******inside findAndWriteDirectReporteesintoPDF******");
        }
        
       
        return raddressEntry;
    }
```

Comment: The above code doesnt show me the checknames dialog box of domain2 to resolve name even after setting domain2 as my default account from accounts.DisplayAccountList() dialog.. where have i gone wrong.. It still shows checknames from domain1 to resolve name